# Ajax call to webservice

Tags: c#, ajax, xml, web-services

I'm trying to make a call using ajax to the web service to verify if a userame and password are correct. I am just returning pass or fail in xml. In my asmx page, I am getting an error "an object is required for the non static field , method, or property 'system.web.ui.page.request.get" Also, my xmlhttp.open URL, Am I doing it right ?  Does anybody has a suggestion on how to solve this? This is my first post, please let me know if I have asked the question wrong or provided insufficient information. Thank you.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string Auth() {
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString;
        string str = null;
        SqlCommand com;
        string query = String.Format("select COUNT(TeacherID) from USERS where User= '{0}' and Password='{1}'", Page.Request.QueryString["username"], Page.Request.QueryString["password"]);
        object obj = null;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        con.Open();
        com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        obj = com.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
        Page.Response.Write(obj);
    }



 function getResult() {

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("lblMessage").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "authenticate.asmx.cs?username=" + document.getElementById("txtUserName").value + "&password=" + document.getElementById("txtPassword").value, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any results, any errors, please provide more info.

Comment: if i put that method inside a page load in my aspx.cs page, it works , returns 1 or 0,  but when I put it in my web service i'm getting "an object is required for the non static field , method, or property 'system.web.ui.page.request.get"  and the underline errors are from Page.Request. and page.Response

Comment: use HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString     and see if it helps...

Comment: Esc, Thank you ! I will read more about httpcontext, and one last thing, my xmlHttp.open URL, I can't get it to to work but the web service works. Also , the tempuri namespace, What would I put there ?

Comment: Please be more precise with that second question, and did the  HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString solve your problem?

Comment: Yes! :) it solved my problem. http://localhost:55555/Authenticate.asmx?op=Auth takes me to the webservice and there's a link for my method auth.

Comment: after the asmx you have to add a slash and then your method name..

Comment: xmlhttp.open("GET", "authenticate.asmx/auth?username=" + document.getElementById("txtUserName").value + "&password=" + document.getElementById("txtPassword").value, true);
does not work

Comment: Here is a sample apply it to your example  :                                             var url = "http://localhost:49216/WebXml" + 
"HttpDemo/SomeService.asmx?op=GetTimeString"

Comment: if i replace  xmlhttp.open("GET", var url = "localhost:49216/WebXml" + "HttpDemo/SomeService.asmx?op=GetTimeString" + document.getElementById("txtUserName").value + "&password=" + document.getElementById("txtPassword").value, true); , 
it says my function getResult is undefined

Comment: Have a look at here and modify your javascript-ajax code then... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23534/Consuming-NET-Web-Services-Using-the-XMLHTTP-Proto

Comment: did you manage to solve that by now? just vote up the given answer for other people to see what the problem was with the webservice. @CompressedAir

Comment: I have not solved it yet, but I feel like you've guided me in the right direction still reading the link you've given me. I can't upvote because i don't have enough stackoverflow cred. I will up vote once I do .

Comment: No problem, Try to solve that on your own, if not I will most likely do that but tomorrow, I am in a rush right now but I feel like you will be able to do that. It's good practice anyway... cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"an object is required for the non static field , method, or property 'system.web.ui.page.request.get"-- this was the actual problem for the webservice. Solved with putting the following code

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["username"],   

HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["password"]);
```

instead of the above posted lines by the user which missed the prefixes.

```
HttpContext.Current.
```

The full code is the following:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Auth() {
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString;
    string str = null;
    SqlCommand com;
    string query = String.Format("select COUNT(TeacherID) from USERS where User= '{0}' and Password='{1}'",  HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["username"],  HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["password"]);
    object obj = null;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    con.Open();
    com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    obj = com.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();
    Page.Response.Write(obj);
}
```